# Glass effect in Android like ios

Tags: android

The buttons in the image have a effect like gradient. How to produce that effect.[image]

Comment: Very simply, use a **9 patch**.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Sir I appreciate you comment .

Comment: I don't have an image. I am using xml to produce that. Able to produce using gradient effect but not equivalent.

Comment: `I don't have an image`... Make it! Use GIMP and make a greyscaled version of the bove picture. Cut it to fit, recolor it and finally make it a 9 patch..

Answer (score 2):

Using **9-patch images** is actually quit simple. Just keep in mind which area is stretched and which area will be repeated.

9-patch could solve your problem .

> http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Please check demo [Apple look on Android Button](http://www.dibbus.com/2012/08/more-buttons/)

You can use [Simple Nine-patch Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

Comment: don't have an image. I am using xml to produce that. Able to produce using gradient effect but not equivalent.

Comment: Anyway, @PrashanthDebbadwar: Consider this: `I don't have an image`... Make it! Use GIMP and make a greyscaled version of the bove picture. Cut it to fit, recolor it and finally make it a 9 patch...

Answer (score 1):

I think by your comments **I don't have an image**, you meant to say **I don't want to use an image**. Well, you can use XML-based gradient. It will probably not look identical, but very close. Here is the code for the first orange button:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient 
    android:type="linear"
    android:centerX="49%" 
    android:startColor="#FFe76f3b" 
    android:centerColor="#FFe76f3b" 
    android:endColor="#FFe25d32" 
    android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

And here is an [online tool to help you generate gradients in different systems](http://angrytools.com/gradient/)